# Why does changing a mutable array contained in a dictionary not require updating the dictionary?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, collections

I was trying a piece of code from CS193P course (Objective-C). I noticed something in the way that the compiler works. An `NSMutableArray` called `photos` was added to an `NSMutableDictionary`, `photosByPhotographer`. Later on, a change was made to `photos` without any changes to `photosByPhotographer`. When I logged `photosByPhotographer`, the change was automatically applied to it and it did not need any extra lines of code!

I wonder how the compiler makes this work? Any materials to read from?

The code is as follows:

```
- (void)updatePhotosByPhotographer
{
    NSMutableDictionary *photosByPhotographer = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSDictionary *photo in self.photos) {
        NSString *photographer = [photo objectForKey:FLICKR_PHOTO_OWNER];
        NSMutableArray *photos = [photosByPhotographer objectForKey:photographer];
        if (!photos) {
            photos = [NSMutableArray array];
            [photosByPhotographer setObject:photos forKey:photographer];
            NSLog(@"photosByPhotographer in if: %@", photosByPhotographer);
        }
        [photos addObject:photo];
        NSLog(@"photosByPhotographer after if: %@", photosByPhotographer);
    }
    self.photosByPhotographer = photosByPhotographer;
}
```

The `NSLog()` result is as follows:

```
2012-07-20 20:05:57.618 Shutterbug[453:f803] photosByPhotographer in if: {
Dowbiggin =     (
);
}

2012-07-20 20:05:57.620 Shutterbug[453:f803] photosByPhotographer after if: {
Dowbiggin =     (
            {
        accuracy = 16;
        context = 0;
        dateupload = 1342836026;
        description =             {
            "_content" = "";
        };
        farm = 9;
        "geo_is_contact" = 0;
        "geo_is_family" = 0;
        "geo_is_friend" = 0;
        "geo_is_public" = 1;
        id = 7612787270;
        isfamily = 0;
        isfriend = 0;
        ispublic = 1;
        latitude = "37.307085";
        longitude = "-121.900395";
        originalformat = jpg;
        originalsecret = 052e70d412;
        owner = "22751315@N05";
        ownername = Dowbiggin;
        "place_id" = cils8sJUV7MeXHwt9A;
        secret = 4437007c99;
        server = 8161;
        tags = "square squareformat iphoneography instagramapp uploaded:by=instagram foursquare:venue=49f13597f964a5209c691fe3";
        title = "My little goofball";
        woeid = 55971033;
    }
);
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the compiler -- it's how mutable objects work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because in Cocoa, you are using objects and pass by reference.

Imagine this code:

```
NSMutableArray *a, *b;

a  = [NSMutableArray new];
[a addObject:@"A"]; // a contains @"A"
b = a; // b is assigned to the same object
[b addObject:@"B"]; // a and b contain @"A", @"B"

NSLog(@"a = %p and b = %p", a, b); // same values
```

The variables `a` and `b` **point** to the same object. You can also see that by comparing the pointer values.

However, if we do the following:

```
NSMutableArray *a, *b;

a  = [NSMutableArray new];
[a addObject:@"A"]; // a contains @"A"
b = [[a mutableCopy] autorelease]; // b is assigned to a COPY of the object
[b addObject:@"B"]; // b contains @"A", @"B", while a still contains @"A"

NSLog(@"a = %p and b = %p", a, b); // NOT the same values
```

`b` is assigned to a copy of `a` (not the original), so `b` points to an other object. You can check by comparing the addresses of the objects.

Answer (score 3):

The `photos` arrays is stored by reference in the NSDictionary, not as a copy. Therefore, if you change the underlying array, you will see that when you access the dictionary.

This is why it can be dangerous to provide some mutable types by reference instead of storing copies of them.

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand how pointers and references work.  Basically rather than variables in your code being actual full structures and objects, generally they are references or pointers to those structures.  You can visualise the concept in a number of ways, but perhaps one that's useful is to think of a variable such as:

```
NSDictionary *myDict;
```

being really just a number which is the memory address of the myDict object.  Here's a visualisation of how it works:

[image]

Your `NSDictionary` reference points to an object in memory which itself holds multiple references to other objects, which can be changed without affecting the dictionary itself. In this example I've shown an `NSArray` having a new object added to it. The reference to the array from the dictionary remains the same.  There is only ever one instance of the array and the objects in it at any time.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `NSLog` on an `NSDictionary` object then its method `description` is called.

In the implementation of the method `description`, `NSDictionary` is calling the `description` method of each value (object) of all its keys.
So when a value (object) changes so does the output of its `description` method change.
That is why it is reflected when calling `NSLog` on an `NSDictionary` object again.