# Adding and modifying NSMutableArray inside NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a function in which an NSMutableDictionary is being populated by the values of an NSMutableArray. This NSMutableArray stores the CGPoints based on the movement of the finger. When touchesEnded is called, the values inside the NSMutableArray is "transferred" into the NSMutableDictionary, then it is emptied. I am doing this just to keep track on the finger movements (and for other purposes).

The problem here is that when the NSMutableArray is emptied, the NSMutableDictionary is emptied as well.

This is my code:

```
[pointDict setObject:pointArr forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
//When I check if the pointDict is not empty, it works fine.
[pointArr removeAllObjects];
//Now when I check if the pointDict is not empty, it returns nothing.
```

Can anyone tell me why is this happening? What's the problem with the code?

Comment: yes, because the `pointDict` contains an empty `NSMutableArray` object. you should remove the `NSMutableArray` from the `pointDict` like this: `[pointDict setObject:NSNull forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];` or `[pointDict removeObjectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]]` if you prefer better this way.

Comment: @holex Calling `setObject:forKey:` with `nil` will throw an exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does changing a mutable array contained in a dictionary not require updating the dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595303/why-does-changing-a-mutable-array-contained-in-a-dictionary-not-require-updating)

Comment: @benzado you are right, I've corrected it to `NSNull`.

Comment: @holex OK, now it won't crash, but you'll have to check the objects you get out of the dictionary to see which are NSArray and which are NSNull. Regardless, this doesn't address user1412469's question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `setObject:forKey:` you are just passing along a pointer to the same object that `pointArr` is pointing to. So when you tell the array to `removeAllObjects`, all the points are gone, because *there is only one array*.

You need to make a copy before you store it. Assuming you are using ARC, and that you don't need to modify the array after you put it in the `pointDict`, you can do this:

```
[pointDict setObject:[pointArr copy] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
```

If you need to keep the array mutable, you can use `mutableCopy` instead.

If you're not using ARC, you will need to use `release` or `autorelease` to release your claim on the the copied array after you put it in the dictionary (since `copy` creates a new object, just like `alloc`, you are responsible for releasing it).

Comment: Or (if not using ARC) just autorelease the copy.

Comment: I'll try this and let you know if it works. Thanks for responding though.